# parsing xml version 2 PHP

Tags: php, xml

Im trying to read a xml version 2 with simpleXMLElement and got errors. Heres my sample xml

```
<?xml version="2.0"?>
<books>
  <book id="978-1594489501">
    <title>My books</title>
    <author>Someone</author>
    <publisher>publisher</publisher>
    <price>14.27</price>
  </book>
</books>
```

PHP code:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('books.xml', null, true);
$attributes = $element->attributes();   // get all attributes
$children   = $element->children();     // get all children

foreach($children as $key => $value){
  echo $value;
}
```

Comment: There are only two versions of XML: 1.0 and 1.1. Where did you get this "2.0" document?

Comment: This version is not an standard yet. http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n2/. Stick to 1.0/1.1